# Running Unit Test Projects on TFS 2010. Team Build 2010 Is Not Compiling Test DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tfsbuild, build-automation

I have set up a TFS 2010 Team Build Configuration to run continuous builds.

I currently have 2 Test Projects that run inside Visual Studio 2010 IDE with no problems.

When I queue the solution (with the test projects) to build, the build log reports:
"No Test Results".

My Build Process parameters **Automated Test Rule** matches my test assembly names:

- Run tests in assemblies matching **\*_Test.dll.

After inspecting the Build folder **C:/Builds/2/[ProjectName]/[BuildName]/Binaries**, I noticed that there were no .dll/.pdb files for my test projects built; even though all other project required dlls are in here.

The Test Project folders **do** exist in **C:/Builds/2/[ProjectName/[BuildName]/Sources**.

My Build Process parameters referenced under "*Items to Build*" => "*Configurations to Build*" :

**Any CPU|Relase**

Under Configuration Manager for my soltuion, for **Any CPU** and **Release**, I *Do* have my Test Projects checked off under the *Build* column.

From all of the documentation I have read, my tests should be running, but from the above inspection it appears that they are not even building.

Any insight or ideas into getting these unit test projects to compile and run on my TFS 2010 Build Server would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the name of your test projects?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using MsTest or NUnit?

Comment: The name of my test projects are of the form: Com.MyCompany.Main_Test.  I fixed the formatting of the pattern matching in my question above.

Comment: Hi Sheldon, we seem to have exactly the same problem of yours and I wonder if you were able to find a solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: @notlkk I am no longer on this project.  I did get it working at some point, but I do not remember the exact steps.  Wish I could tell you more.  I would try a small solution (1 project, 1 test) and see if you can get that working and maybe see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the build, you can point to the vsmdi file instead of putting in the wildcard. Does that yield the same result?